# How to prevent PictureBox internally refreshes itself?

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, gdi+

I have a very fast loop which renders animation in a Bitmap buffer and adds filter to it (by using LockBits/UnlockBits to access to the raw data and Marshaling changes to it.) in an independent thread.

I wanted to figure out a way to display the render on the Form, real-time, so I created a PictureBox and linked its Image to the bitmap I created. Everytime immediately after the bitmap is unlocked, I refreshed the PictureBox (using delegate, to do cross-threading) so that the rendering is updated properly.

It's totally fine and works very fast, but one big problem came out as I tried dragging the form to the border of the screen, to see if any bug would appear, and oops, the app collapse..saying 'the bitmap is being locked' This happens when either there's other window moving above the PictureBox or the PictureBox is dragged partially out of the screen. I suspice it because PictureBox can refresh itself when redraw is neccessary, and it does when the bitmap is still being locked. So...any way to sovle this problem? Or anyother ways to render the my animation better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that.

Instead, you should copy the image (on the background thread) and put the copy in the PictureBox.

For better performance, you can swap between two images to avoid creating too many images.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm going to see how this will perform. And also thank @Tigran your solution is also very helpful indeed.

Answer (score 1):

One of **possible** solutions could be is create your custom `MyPictureBox : PictureBox` (say) class which override `OnPaintBackground`, like this:

```
protected override OnPaintBackground(...)
{
   // nothing, an empty method
}
```

*But I'm not very sure that this will work, you should to check this by yourself.*

What *I* would do, personally, considering your comment:

> I have a very fast loop which renders animation in a Bitmap buffer and
>   adds filter to it (by using LockBits/UnlockBits to access to the raw
>   data and Marshaling changes to it.) in an independent thread

just forget about `PictureBox`, cause I found it, personally, too generic and non suitable for high performance rendering. Just write a simple class that handles the drawing of specified bitmap on specified surface.

Imo, this is a best choice.

Comment: #2: That will just re-invent `PictureBox`; it won't help.

Comment: @SLaks: I wouldn't recommend to *re-invent* a `PictureBox`, but extract from the concept only ideas you need (if there is no other solution, in this case seems so), and implement them. Don't think he will need rewrite *all* functions available in `PB`, just a couple of them he needs.

Comment: There's still no point; that will have the same problem.  You need to be able to redraw on demand.

Comment: @SLaks: by implementing them, you have much more control over `OS` message pumping where you definitely don't have on built-in controls, like `PB`. Using `double-buffering` ad clever redrawing you can achieve much more then standard controls can do.

Comment: Double buffering alone won't help; you need to maintain a separate copy of the image.  (exactly as I answered)

Comment: @SLaks: naturally, double buffering is technique for handling single frame print. If you refer to animation, you need to cash/preload/other.. in some way the data in order to maintain the fluid rendering.